# Facebook graph real-time updates, verify callback_url on local

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In my development enviroment (localhost of course).
Based on this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) I've sucessfully created a apps token with this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<app-id>&client_secret=<app-secret>&grant_type=client_credentials
```

then make post request to verify my callback_url to FB graph, like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<app-id>/subscriptions?access_token=my_apps_access_token=user&fields=first_name&callback_url=http://localhost:3000&verify_token=mystringtoken
```

but it's always return :

```
 {"error":{"message":"(#2200) callback verification failed: ","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

(I've try using lvh.me:3000)

Is there possible to verify the callback_url using localhost?

Comment: Erm, ignoring the auth problems you'd need to provide an *actual URL* that is reachable from the internet.

Comment: I use heroku for that.. the verification callback_url is sucessfull but there's another problem.. when the app user change somthing that the apps already subscribed (first_name, last_name and music) facebook didn't hit the callback_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the API documentation:

```
Your callback server must handle two types of requests.

Facebook servers will make a single HTTP GET to your callback URL when you try to add or modify a subscription. After a successful subscription, Facebook servers will notify your server of changes by issuing HTTP POST requests to the same URL.
```

From this statement, I would presume that you must provide a publicly accessible URL.

Comment: Can we use public ip address instead?

Comment: No, not an IP, it must be a valid https URL (which might contain an IP address) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks#setup

Answer (score 0):

Here is [How to](/questions/9140612/how-to-test-facebook-real-time-updates) . I've explained the proccess.